# Rendering coloured text in the echo area

Tags: echo-area, message

I want to print in the echo area a coloured label with a description, but cannot get the colour to render properly.

```lisp
(defun echos (label text)
  "Display label with text in the Echo Area."
  (let* ((label-colour "red")
         (clabel (propertize label 'face `(:foreground ,label-colour))))
    (message "%s %s" clabel text)))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*cannot get the colour to render properly*"?

Comment: BTW, I recommend you post *well-formatted* code next time. And don't simply cut a snippet from your buffer with *those variables whose names' meanings are unknown*; choose some meaningful name, and try to let people know what you want.

Comment: `clabel` is not printed with red foreground.

Comment: 1) You changed those names, good. 2) what did you see in echo area? Something like this `#("clabel text" 0 6 (face (:foreground "red")))`?

Comment: Correct.  That's what actually gets printed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate. The confusion between printing a returned value and printing as a side effect is a common gotcha. Maybe Someone(TM) has the time to search for the dup(s) - likely with `M-:`, `C-x C-e`, and similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-x C-e` will evaluate that expression first and then display the **returned value** from that expression.

So after you `C-x C-e` `(echos "clabel" "text")`,

1. The **rendered text is displayed** in echo area, lasting for several milliseconds/nanoseconds.
2. Then the **returned value** from `(echos "clabel" "text")`, which is `#("clabel text" 0 6 (face (:foreground "red")))`, is be displayed in echo area.

So, to observe the rendered text better, evaluate this:

```lisp
(prog1 (echos "clabel" "text")
  (sleep-for 1))
```

---

Or use `C-j` if you are using `lisp-interaction-mode`.

Comment: Why does display in colour, then change to `#("clabel text" 0 6 (face (:foreground "red")))` ?

Comment: If I call `(echos "clabel" "text")` from an interactive function, label gets printed in red as expected.  No reed for sleeping at all.

Comment: @Dilna: So you should read my answer carefully

Comment: This effect happens with `C-x C-e`.  Why does it not execute the same as with using it in elisp code ?

Comment: @Dilna: Because that is `C-x C-e`'s feature.  It just does that way.

Comment: FWIW: OP doesn't read carefully, in general: Questions that OP posts (versus what OP might think OP asked); answers to those questions; or comments on those questions and answers. Nor does OP invest in reading Emacs `*Help*` or manuals. Kind of a waste of time for well-meaning interlocutors here. By now, one would think that the message might have been received, and that OP would start helping OP.